# wordpress google analytics function.php issues

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

Hi can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to add the google analytics as per instructions on multiple sources but it keeps crashing my site no matter where I put the information Here is the code as I tried this last time for the 7th time., Below is the contents of the function.php code:

```
    <?php

add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_add_googleanalytics');
function wpb_add_googleanalytics() { ?>

// Paste your Google Analytics code from Step 4 here
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-xxx');
</script>

function denRegScript(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datatable-css', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/datatables.css'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'datatables-js', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/datatables.min.js'), array('jquery'), '0.1', true ); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','denRegScript');


add_action('wp_ajax_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
//add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
function datatables_server_side_callback()
{

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $request = $_GET;

    $json_pre_result = newfunc($request);

    if(isset($json_pre_result)) {
        echo json_encode($json_pre_result);
    }

    wp_die();

}

function newfunc($request){

        global $wpdb;

        // $catnamewithid = $wpdb->get_results( 
        //     "SELECT id_category,category_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories", OBJECT_K
        // );
        $data = array();
        $maincatParam = $request['maincat'];
        $subcatParam = $request['subcat'];
        error_log($maincatParam);
        error_log($subcatParam);
        $regionParam = $regionParamOrig = $request['region'];
        $regionParam = explode(", ",$regionParam);
        if(isset($regionParam[0]) && isset($regionParam[1])){
            $regionParamCity = $regionParam[0];
            $regionParamstate = $regionParam[1];
        }else{
            $regionParamCity = $regionParamstate = $regionParamOrig;
        }

        $empsql = "";
        if($regionParamCity!="all"){
            // find the employer ids
            $employeeresults = $wpdb->get_results(
                "SELECT id_professional FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_professionals WHERE `pro_address` LIKE '%, $regionParamstate%' OR `pro_address` LIKE '%$regionParamCity%' ", ARRAY_A
            );

            if(!empty($employeeresults)){
                $te3 = array();
                foreach ($employeeresults as $value) {
                    array_push($te3,$value['id_professional']);
                }
                $subEmpString = join(",",$te3);
                $empsql = "AND id_employer IN ($subEmpString)";
            }

        }


        if($maincatParam==-1){
            $allMainCats = $wpdb->get_results( 
                "SELECT id_category,category_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_parent IN (0) ", OBJECT_K
            );
            // need to return all data
        }else{
            $allMainCats = $wpdb->get_results( 
                "SELECT id_category,category_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_category IN ($maincatParam) ", OBJECT_K
            );
        }



        $superFArray = array();

        foreach ($allMainCats as $maincategoryid => $maincategorynameArray) {

            $subcatids = array();
            if($subcatParam==-1){
                $subcategries = $wpdb->get_results( 
                    "SELECT id_category,category_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_parent IN ($maincategoryid) AND id_category NOT BETWEEN 123 AND 198 ", OBJECT_K
                );
            }else{
                $subcategries = $wpdb->get_results( 
                    "SELECT id_category,category_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_category IN ($subcatParam) AND id_category NOT BETWEEN 123 AND 198 ", OBJECT_K
                );
                //$subcategries = getSingleSubCat($subcatParam);
            }


            $tempar1 = array();
            // find wage for all sub category id of this main category and assign sub cat id as key, assign wages as values
            $implodedsubcatid = "";


            if(!empty($subcategries)){
                $fored = array();
                $te3 = array();
                $budgetarrayforcat = array();
                foreach ($subcategries as $subcategoryid => $subcategoryname) {
                    array_push($te3,$subcategoryid);
                }
                $implodedsubcatid = join(",",$te3);

                // Hourly
                $jobsresults2 = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "SELECT id_category,job_budget FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_job WHERE id_category IN ($implodedsubcatid) AND job_payment_type='Per hour' $empsql ORDER BY job_budget LIMIT 100 ", ARRAY_A
                );
                if(!empty($jobsresults2)){


                    // make new array of obj_k

                    foreach ($jobsresults2 as $key => $jobline) {
                        $catid = $jobline['id_category'];
                        $rawbudget = $jobline['job_budget'];

                        $averageofone = 0;
                        $explodeall = explode(" ",$rawbudget);

                        if (($key = array_search("00", $explodeall)) !== false) {
                            unset($explodeall[$key]);
                        }
                        if(count($explodeall)) {
                            $a = array_filter($explodeall, function($explodeall) { return is_numeric($explodeall) == true; });
                            //$a = array_filter($explodeall);
                            $averageofone = array_sum($a)/count($a);
                        }
                        $budget = $averageofone;

                        $fored[$catid]['hour'][] = $budget;
                    }

                    // foreach ($fored as $subcatid => $job_budget) {
                    //  $budg = $job_budget['job_budget'];
                    //  $budgetarrayforcat[$subcatid]['hour'][] = $budg;
                    // }
                }

                  // Week
                $jobsresults = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "SELECT id_category,job_budget FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_job WHERE id_category IN ($implodedsubcatid) AND job_payment_type='Weekly' $empsql ORDER BY job_budget LIMIT 100 ", ARRAY_A
                );
                if(!empty($jobsresults)){


                    // make new array of obj_k

                    foreach ($jobsresults as $key => $jobline) {
                        $catid = $jobline['id_category'];
                        $rawbudget = $jobline['job_budget'];

                        $averageofone = 0;
                        $explodeall = explode(" ",$rawbudget);

                        if (($key = array_search("00", $explodeall)) !== false) {
                            unset($explodeall[$key]);
                        }
                        if(count($explodeall)) {
                            $a = array_filter($explodeall, function($explodeall) { return is_numeric($explodeall) == true; });
                            //$a = array_filter($explodeall);
                            if(count($a)!=0){
                            $averageofone = array_sum($a)/count($a);
                            }
                        }
                        $budget = $averageofone;

                        $fored[$catid]['week'][] = $budget;
                    }

                    // foreach ($fored as $subcatid => $job_budget) {
                    //  $budg = $job_budget['job_budget'];
                    //  $budgetarrayforcat[$subcatid]['hour'][] = $budg;
                    // }
                }


                $newfored = array();
                foreach ($fored as $catid => $value) {
                    foreach ($value as $daytype => $average) {

                        if(count($average)!=0){
                            $sav = array_sum($average)/count($average);
                        }else{
                            $sav = 0;
                        }

                        switch ($daytype) {
                            case "month":
                                $newfored[$catid]['month'] = $sav;
                                //$averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Monthly: </span>".$average."<br/>";
                                break;
                            case "week":
                                $newfored[$catid]['week'] = $sav;
                                //$averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Weekly: </span>".$average."<br/>";
                                break;
                            case "hour":
                                $newfored[$catid]['hour'] = $sav;
                                //$averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Hourly:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$average."<br/>";
                                break;
                            default:

                        }
                    }
                }

            }


            foreach ($subcategries as $subcategoryid => $subcategoryname) {
                $wages = array();
                if(isset($newfored[$subcategoryid])){
                    $wages = $newfored[$subcategoryid];
                }
                $subcategoryname->wages = $wages;
                $tempar1[$subcategoryid] = $subcategoryname;
            }
            $maincategoryname = $maincategorynameArray->category_title;
            $superFArray[$maincategoryname] = $tempar1;


        }


        foreach ($superFArray as $maincatname => $subarray) {

            foreach ($subarray as $subvalue) {
                if(!empty($subvalue->wages)){
                $nestedData = array();
                $subcatname = $subvalue->category_title;
                $averageString = '';



                foreach ($subvalue->wages as $daytype => $average) {
                    $average = money_format('$%i', $average);

                    $breakweek = false;
                    if(isset($subvalue->wages['hour']) && isset($subvalue->wages['week']) ){
                        if($subvalue->wages['hour']>$subvalue->wages['week']){
                            $breakweek = true;
                        }
                    }

                            switch ($daytype) {
                                case "month":
                                    $averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Monthly: </span>".$average."<br/>";
                                    break;
                                case "week":
                                    if(!$breakweek){
                                        $averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Weekly: </span>".$average."<br/>";
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "hour":
                                    $averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Hourly:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$average."<br/>";
                                    break;
                                default:

                            }

                }


                $nestedData[] = $maincatname;
                $nestedData[] = $subcatname;
                $nestedData[] = $averageString;

                $data[] = $nestedData;
                }
            }
        }

        $final_data = array(
            "draw" => intval($request['draw']),
            "recordsTotal" => count($data),
            //"recordsFiltered" => 12,
            "data" => $data
        );
        return $final_data;

}

function get_pre_json_time_sheets($request){
    $columns=array(
        0=>'name',
        1=>'date',
        2=>'starttime',
        3=>'endtime',
    );

    // $posts_per_page = $request['length'];
    // $doffset = $request['start'];
    // $order = $request['order'][0]['dir'];
    // $orderby = $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']];
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array();
    $maincatParam = $request['maincat'];
    $subcatParam = $request['subcat'];
    $regionParam = $regionParamOrig = $request['region'];
    $regionParam = explode(", ",$regionParam);
    if(isset($regionParam[0]) && isset($regionParam[1])){
        $regionParamCity = $regionParam[0];
        $regionParamstate = $regionParam[1];
    }else{
        $regionParamCity = $regionParamstate = $regionParamOrig;
    }

    $subEmpString = "";
    $empsql = "";
    if($regionParamCity!="all"){
        // find the employer ids
        $employeeresults = $wpdb->get_results( 
            "SELECT id_professional FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_professionals WHERE `pro_address` LIKE '%, $regionParamstate%' OR `pro_address` LIKE '%$regionParamCity%' ", ARRAY_A
        );

        if(!empty($employeeresults)){
            $te3 = array();
            foreach ($employeeresults as $value) {
                array_push($te3,$value['id_professional']);
            }
            $subEmpString = join(",",$te3);
            $empsql = "AND id_employer IN ($subEmpString)";
        }

    }

    $nestedData = array();
    $budgetarrayforcat = array();
    $maincatbudgetarray = array();


    $catnamewithid = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT id_category,category_title FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories", OBJECT_K
    );
    //error_log(print_r($catnamewithid,true));


    if($maincatParam==-1){
        $allMainCat = getIMainCat();      
        // need to return all data
    }else{
        $allMainCat = getSingleMainCat($maincatParam);
    }



    if(!empty($allMainCat)){
        foreach ($allMainCat as $singlemain) {
           $maincatid = $singlemain->id_category;
           $maincatname = $singlemain->category_title;

           if($subcatParam==-1){
                $subcatids = getsubcatidsStringOfMainCat($maincatid);
           }else{
                $subcatids = $subcatParam;
           }

           if(!empty($subcatids)){

            // Week
           $jobsresults = $wpdb->get_results( 
                     "SELECT job_budget,id_category FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_job WHERE id_category IN ($subcatids) AND job_payment_type = 'Weekly' $empsql ORDER BY job_budget LIMIT 12 ", ARRAY_A
           );
           //(job_budget like '%per week%' OR job_budget like '%week%')
           if(!empty($jobsresults)){
               foreach ($jobsresults as $key => $jobline) {
                   $budg = $jobline['job_budget'];
                   $idcat = $jobline['id_category'];
                   if(isset($catnamewithid[$idcat]->category_title)){
                   $idname = $catnamewithid[$idcat]->category_title;
                   $budgetarrayforcat[$idname]['week'][] = $budg;
                   }
               }
           }


           // Hourly
           $jobsresults2 = $wpdb->get_results( 
            "SELECT job_budget,id_category FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_job WHERE id_category IN ($subcatids) AND job_payment_type='Per hour' $empsql ORDER BY job_budget LIMIT 12 ", ARRAY_A
            );
            //(job_budget like '%per hour%' OR job_budget like '%hourly%' )

            if(!empty($jobsresults2)){
                foreach ($jobsresults2 as $key => $jobline) {
                    $budg = $jobline['job_budget'];
                    $idcat = $jobline['id_category'];
                    if(isset($catnamewithid[$idcat]->category_title)){
                    $idname = $catnamewithid[$idcat]->category_title;
                    $budgetarrayforcat[$idname]['hour'][] = $budg;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Anually
        //    $jobsresults3 = $wpdb->get_results( 
        //     "SELECT job_budget,id_category FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_job WHERE id_category IN ($subcatids) AND (job_budget like '%per month%' OR job_budget like '%monthly%') $empsql LIMIT 12", ARRAY_A
        //     );

        //     if(!empty($jobsresults3)){
        //         foreach ($jobsresults3 as $key => $jobline) {
        //             $budg = $jobline['job_budget'];
        //             $idcat = $jobline['id_category'];
        //             if(isset($catnamewithid[$idcat]->category_title)){
        //             $idname = $catnamewithid[$idcat]->category_title;
        //             $budgetarrayforcat[$idname]['month'][] = $budg;
        //             }
        //         }
        //     }



           $maincatbudgetarray[$maincatname] = $budgetarrayforcat;
        }
        }
    }
        //error_log(print_r($maincatbudgetarray,true));
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($maincatbudgetarray);
        echo '</pre>';


        foreach ($maincatbudgetarray as $maincatname => $subcatarray) {



            foreach ($subcatarray as $subcatname => $wagearray) {
                    $nestedData = array();

                    // we have week and hour array here in $wagearray
                    $averageString = "";

                    foreach ($wagearray as $daytype => $singlewage) {

                                    $countjobs = count($singlewage);
                                    $allave = array();
                                    foreach ($singlewage as $rawtext) {
                                            $averageofone = 0;
                                            $explodeall = explode(" ",$rawtext);

                                            if (($key = array_search("00", $explodeall)) !== false) {
                                                unset($explodeall[$key]);
                                            }
                                            if(count($explodeall)) {
                                                $a = array_filter($explodeall, function($explodeall) { return is_numeric($explodeall) == true; });
                                                $a = array_filter($explodeall);
                                                $averageofone = array_sum($a)/count($a);
                                            }
                                            array_push($allave,$averageofone);
                                    }
                                    $average = money_format('$%i', array_sum($allave)/$countjobs);

                        switch ($daytype) {
                            case "month":
                                $averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Monthly: </span>".$average."<br/>";
                            break;
                            case "week":
                                $averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Weekly: </span>".$average."<br/>";
                                break;
                            case "hour":
                                $averageString .=  "<span class='fixwl'>Hourly:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$average."<br/>";
                                break;
                            default:

                        }


                    }

                        $nestedData[] = $maincatname;
                        $nestedData[] = $subcatname;
                        $nestedData[] = $averageString;
                        $data[] = $nestedData;
            }

        }




    $final_data = array(
        "draw" => intval($request['draw']),
        "recordsTotal" => count($data),
        "recordsFiltered" => 12,
        "data" => $data
    );
    return $final_data;
}

function getsubcatidsStringOfMainCat($maincat){
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT id_category FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_parent IN ($maincat) AND id_category NOT BETWEEN 123 AND 198", ARRAY_A
    );

    if(!empty($results)){
        $te2 = array();
        foreach ($results as $value) {
            array_push($te2,$value['id_category']);
        }
        $subCatString = join(",",$te2);

    }
    //error_log(print_r($subCatString,true));
    return $subCatString;
    //wp_die();
}

function getIMainCat(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_parent IN (0) "
    );

    return $results;
    //wp_die();
}

function getSingleMainCat($catid){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_category IN ($catid) "
    );

    return $results;
    //wp_die();
}

function getSingleSubCat($catid){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_category IN ($catid) "
    );

    return $results;
    //wp_die();
}



add_action('wp_ajax_changesubcategorydropdown_action', 'changesubcategorydropdown');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_changesubcategorydropdown_action', 'changesubcategorydropdown');
function changesubcategorydropdown(){

        if(!isset($_POST['maincategory'])) 
            return;

        if( isset($_POST['maincategory']) && $_POST['maincategory']<0 ) 
            return;

        header("Content-Type: application/json");

        $main_category  = $_POST['maincategory'];

        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}expert_jobs_categories WHERE id_parent IN ($main_category) AND id_category NOT BETWEEN 123 AND 198 "
        );

        echo json_encode($results);
        wp_die();

}


function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page ('covid-19-resources-for-artists')) { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // your javscript code goes here
          function gotosite() {
  window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value; // JQuery:  $("#menu").val();
}// your javscript code goes here
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

Have also tried adding it like this outside of the main php tags -

```
    <?php
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_add_googleanalytics');
function wpb_add_googleanalytics() { ?>

// Paste your Google Analytics code from Step 4 here
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-xxx');
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Since I cant place this in a comment here is additional commentary based on the very kind assistance provided so far:

=================================================================================

Thanks but sorry I dont understand. If I literally copy and paste what you have written then it breaks the page. If I compare the first lines of your code to the top of the lines of code that exists then they too are different.

```
<?php
function denRegScript() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'datatable-css',
    get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/datatables.css'),
    false
  );
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'datatables-js',
    get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/datatables.min.js'),
    array('jquery'),
    '0.1',
    true
  );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','denRegScript');

// …

compared to current lines-27:

<?php

function denRegScript(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datatable-css', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/datatables.css'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'datatables-js', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/datatables.min.js'), array('jquery'), '0.1', true ); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','denRegScript');


add_action('wp_ajax_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
//add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
function datatables_server_side_callback()
{

    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $request = $_GET;

    $json_pre_result = newfunc($request);

    if(isset($json_pre_result)) {
        echo json_encode($json_pre_result);
    }

    wp_die();

If I just copy this portion:
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if ( is_page( 'covid-19-resources-for-artists' ) ) { 
  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function gotosite() {
        window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value; // JQuery:  $("#menu").val();
      }
    </script>

  <?php
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript' );

function wpb_add_googleanalytics() {
?>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxx"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-xxx');
  </script>

<?php
}
```

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_add_googleanalytics' );

and place it in the last portion of the code then it does nothing when I code inspect and check the head, there is no analytics code called. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your [PHP opening and closing tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) are incorrect.

They should look like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_add_googleanalytics' );

function wpb_add_googleanalytics() {
?>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxx"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-xxx');
  </script>

<?php
}

function denRegScript() {
    // …
```

---

**Edit:** You could place your Google Analytics code at the end of `functions.php`, and your PHP opening/closing tags would look like this:

```php
<?php
function denRegScript() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'datatable-css',
    get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/datatables.css'),
    false
  );
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'datatables-js',
    get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/datatables.min.js'),
    array('jquery'),
    '0.1',
    true
  );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','denRegScript');

// …

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if ( is_page( 'covid-19-resources-for-artists' ) ) { 
  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function gotosite() {
        window.location = document.getElementById("menu").value; // JQuery:  $("#menu").val();
      }
    </script>

  <?php
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript' );

function wpb_add_googleanalytics() {
?>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxx"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-xxx');
  </script>

<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_add_googleanalytics' );
```

Comment: thank you. And does it matter where it goes? What about the main code? Is that closed correctly elsewhere in the file like at he end of the existing code?

Tried placing it at the end and got this error that again broke he site:
Invalid backend response.
Error occurred on the server side.
HTTP error 500

Comment: @brettm I took a quick look and the rest of your opening/closing tags seem fine to me. Keep in mind that you provided about 600 lines of code, so I can't really inspect every single one of them. You should try to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for questions on Stack Overflow. As for your question: No, it doesn't matter where in the file you place it (since you're hooking into [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/)).

Comment: @brettm A 500 HTTP status code means there was an internal server error, so an error with your PHP code. You have to enable [debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and read the contents of your log file to understand more about it.

Comment: thanks. Was particularity interested in closing of the php tag in the original code. Any idea why the php code that you properly closed when placed at the start of a document before any other cod ro the PHP opener would crash the entire site?

Comment: @brettm You don't have to worry about the closing tag. Per the PHP manual, if a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file.

Comment: @brettm I edited my answer to include an example with the Google Analytics code placed at the end of `functions.php`. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: thanks but i am still missing something since doing the above breaks the page or simply doesn't call the code. Since I can not post a long enough comment here, I went and added my comment and additional question with example to the original post below the " ===" line